# How to most efficently find the index of an item in an array with only two types of items 0, 1 in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Say for instance you have

```
var arr = [0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1];
```

And you want to find the position of the first 1 with reference to the first 0.
`arr.indexOf` would solve the problem directly but I'm not sure if it compares linearly each item in the array? A binary search wouldn't work because you would loose the index if you sort and then look for the element... Any other way to get to that first 1 and say aha! index 3, without going one element at a time?

Comment: What do you mean by "with reference to the first 0"?

Comment: You can't do better than a linear search since each element before the first `1` must be checked. In contrast, the reason a binary search works is because the list is sorted and there is information contained in each element (i.e. all elements before any given element is less than or equal to it). There is no such structure in your case.

Comment: @user2357112 with reference to the first 0 I mean with reference to arr[0]; so for instance the first 1 has an idex of 3 with reference to the first 0. If it was with reference to the second 0 it would have index 2

Comment: What do you mean by "with reference to"?

Comment: if that were the case, a nested indexOf() would work.

Comment: @dandavis what do you mean by a nested indexOf ?

Comment: `arr.indexOf(1, arr.indexOf(0))`

Comment: Do you have the starting point, or do you need to locate it too? Your description is confusing. Seems like something very simple but you're shrouding it in vague language.

Comment: @dandavis wouldn't indexOf still do a linear search starting from indexOf(0)?

Comment: @squint The starting point says "with reference to the first 0" in this case its arr[0]. if you had [1,1,1,0,0,0] it would be with reference to arr[3]

Comment: how js works under the hood is not my concern and subject to updates over time, but indexOf() would be by far the most efficient way to find the index of something (hence the name). you could use an object or object elements to keep a ref if you don't like searching.

Comment: And as I asked, do you have the starting point or do you need to locate that too? If you have it, then obviously you just need to start there instead of index `0`. If not, then you're back to a linear search.

Comment: I know that [this is not efficient](http://jsfiddle.net/evuskpgp/1/)...it looks like `.join()` is linear based on the ECMAScript 5.1 spec...but hey that was my attempt at doing it creatively.

Comment: @AlexW: not very; join would have to look at every element in the array. if, however, you converted the array to a string, and could search that many times (without it going stale), "".indexOf() is a lot faster than [].indexOf(). in the case of 1 and 0, the string would work just fine, the indexes are identical...

Comment: If you were hoping there was some sort of compressed format that holds such arrays with offsets that could be automatically read, there isn't (or at least none that you could access from JS if there is). You could however make your own if you control the data source and don't mind an alternate structure.

Comment: @squint you mean if we did something like arr = [{0:0},{1:0},{2,0},{3,1},{4,2}], thus then sorting, binary searching and bringing the key index back?

Comment: I mean something more like an array of indices. Since all values are `0` or `1`, you could get by with simply having sort of like an array of virtual indices that describe at what point it changes from `0` to `1` and vice versa. This would be most beneficial if you think you'll have many sequences of repeating numbers. There'll probably be other overhead considerations, so it's hard to say if it's worthwhile.

Comment: ...as an example, if you had a list like this `[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1]`, the only data you actually need to represent that list is the starting number and the indices at which the number changes. So you'd represent the starting number as `0` and then the list of indices where the changes happen as `[4,7,8,9,12,14]`. I guess you'd also need a final number in the list that would represent one beyond the last index, so `18`. Now you have a compressed list as well as a constant time reference to the info you need. Again, I don't know the use case here but maybe worth considering.

Comment: ...you could also represent the changes as a list of times the current number repeats, so with the start as `0`, you could do `[4,3,1,3,2,4]`. Or you could represent it both ways and use whichever list makes sense at a given time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It searches iteratively from the beginning of the array.

The relevant part of the specification:

Repeat, while `k < len`

- Let `k` Present be the result of calling the `[[HasProperty]]` internal method of `O` with argument `ToString(k)`.
- If `k` Present is true, then

  - Let elementK be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with the argument `ToString(k)`.
  - Let same be the result of applying the Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm to `searchElement` and `elementK`.
  - If same is true, return `k`.
- Increase `k` by 1.

Source: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.14

And yes, as soon as there are no guarantees about the array structure - there is nothing more efficient than a linear search.

I'm not sure how one makes the formal proof for absence of something though.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If you have some justification for why a linear search is the fastest (I think it probably is), then you could include it in your answer.

Comment: @Quirliom I have just added the last phrase. Thanks for -1

Answer (score 0):

I have an efficient method.

instance you have

```
var arr = [0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1];
```

and you create a new array of sum = {sum[i] = ∑(arr[j],j<=i)}

```
var sum = [0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4];
```

so,you can use binary search to find the first sum[j]==1

but if we update the element of arr ,we will calculate sum again with O（n）

There are some data structure like segment tree(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) and Binary Indexed Tree(BIT https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-indexed-trees/)can solve this problem,it allows querying and updating the sum of a range with O(logn)

Therefore,you can solve this problem with O(logn)*O(logn)

Comment: by creating the new array you are already looping through the first array in order to add the previous value, hence you already went through the 1 that you are looking for.

Comment: Use segment tree or BIT,there is no need to calculate the sum of array.Because it can calculate the sum of a range with O(logn)

Answer (score -4):

You could go through the array iteratively but stop once you find the first 1. For example, you could use the following code:

```
boolean found = false;
int arr = {0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1};

for (int i = 0; found != true && i <arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] == '1'){
    found = true;
    }
```

Comment: You're (mostly) reinventing the `break` statement. Plus the `i` will be off by `1`. And your syntax is wrong.

Comment: @chunkyturtle that would be a linear search, looking for something faster than that.